# adding new column by condition with duplicated rows in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There is data:

```
task_id frame   m_label 
466     15    Other 
466     376   Other 
466     376   Snapshot  
477     5053  Snapshot      
477     5053  Transverse
```

`task_id`, `frame` and `m_label`. I need to add a new column ("Snapshot plus"), which contains only data where in same `task_id` the knowledge in the `frame` column matches and where when there is a `snapshot` entry in the `m_label` column. For example line 4, in `frame` 376 the record in the new column will be "Snapshot | Other ", because the `task_id` is the same, and the `Frame` is the same.
Output required:

```
task_id frame   m_label  Snapshot plus       Test
466     15    Other 
466     376   Other 
466     376   Snapshot  Snapshot|Other
477     5053  Snapshot  Snapshot|Transverse 
477     5053  Transverse
488     677   Snapshot                       Only one
```

I wrote the code, here's an example, but it seems to me there are more elegant and clever solutions:

```
#drop duplicates to another frame
df_dup=df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=['frame'],keep='first'),:]    
df_dr=df.drop_duplicates(subset='frame', keep='first')
# merge inner duplicates df and no duplicatets df
merge_df = df_dr.merge(df_dup,on=['task_id', 'frame'],how='inner')
# apply lambda by row for create new column with condition
merge_df['Snapshot plus']=merge_df.apply(lambda row: '|'+ row['m_label_x']+'|'+row['m_label_y']
                                            if (row['m_label_x']=='Snapshot' or row['m_label_y']=='Snapshot' )
                                            else '', axis='columns')  
merge_df = merge_df[['task_id','frame','Snapshot plus']]      
# merge with original df
df_df = df.merge(merge_df, on=['task_id','frame'], how='left')  
# add new column to check if any snapshot label alone in frame and task            
df_df['Test'] = (df_df.groupby(['task_id', 'frame'])
                ['m_label']
                .transform(lambda x: len(x)<2 and
                                     'Snapshot' in x.values
                           )
                .map({True: 'Only one', False: ''})
              )
# again drop duplicates
df_fin=df_df.drop_duplicates(subset=['frame','Snapshot plus'], keep='first')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df["task_id//frame"]=df[["task_id","frame"]].apply(lambda x: str(x[0])+","+str(x[1]),axis=1)
```

[image]

```
Dict={}
for m,Id in zip(df["m_label"].values,df["task_id//frame"].values):
    if m!="Snapshot":
        Dict[Id]=m
```

Dict={'466,15': 'Other', '466,376': 'Other', '477,5053': 'Transverse'}

```
def Arrange_snaps(row):
    if row[0]=="Snapshot":
        print(row[1])
        if row[1] in Dict.keys():
            result=str(row[0])+"|"+str(Dict[row[1]])
        else:
            result=""
        return result
    else:
        return ""
df["Snapshot plus"]=df[["m_label","task_id//frame"]].apply(Arrange_snaps,axis=1)
```

[image]

For a new dataframe:

[image]

Comment: thank you for answer, but only one issue: if label "Snapshot" only one (no other snapshot in this frame) function doesn't work. For example if in frame 5053 only Snapshot label without Transverse

Comment: Hmm, couldn't understand what you mean can you clarify a little bit more?

Comment: Let's new dataframe, so in row 4: `task_id`=477, `frame`=5053,`m_label`=Snapshot, next row with `task_id`=477,  be `frame`=5054,`m_label`=Transverse. So in `frame`=5053 you have only `Snapshot` and nothing else. So function return KeyError: 477,5053

Comment: I've realized what you mean I've forgotten to add a if condition I've updated the answer in my code It works for that condition now.